# SQLAlchemy ForeignKey relation via an intermediate table

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Suppose that I have a table `Articles`, which has fields `article_id`, `content` and it contains one article with id `1`.

I also have a table `Categories`, which has fields `category_id` (primary key), `category_name`, and it contains one category with id `10`.

Now suppose that I have a table `ArticleProperties`, that adds properties to `Articles`. This table has fields `article_id`, `property_name`, `property_value`.

Suppose that I want to create a mapping from `Categories` to `Articles` via `ArticleProperties` table.

I do this by inserting the following values in the `ArticleProperties` table: (article_id=1, property_name="category", property_value=10).

Is there any way in SQLAlchemy to express that rows in table `ArticleProperties` with `property_name` "category" are actually FOREIGN KEYS of table `Articles` to table `Categories`?

This is a complicated problem and I haven't found an answer myself.

Any help appreciated!

Thanks, Boda Cydo.

Comment: george, i had data inserted in it. after your edit, no one knows that article_id=1 is the only article i had in the table, and property_value=10 means that i had only one category with category_id=10.

Comment: Why do you so badly want to put the Categories into the big (and generic) list of ArticleProperties?

Comment: Because Category is not much different from any other property of the article... I am just trying to logically isolate an Article, because Article is by itself, just a piece of text.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understand you question correctly, then No, you can't model that relationship as you have suggested.  (It would help if you described your desired result, rather than your perceived solution)

What I think you may want is a many-to-many mapping table called ArticleCategories, consisting of 2 int columns, ArticleID and CategoryID (with respective FKs)

Comment: An article can have many properties - category, who was the last to edit the article, phase of moon the article was created, or anything you can imagine. 

I can't model it as ArticleCategories, or ArticleMoonPhase, as there are infinite number of properties (which names I sometimes don't even know - users who create articles add properties to it).

Comment: The end result is that when I do something like Article.property_name and have sqlalchemy automatically figure out the value.

In my simple example .property_name would be .category, and sqlalchemy would know that .category is a foreign key on Categories table, and instead of returning id=10, it would know that .category is a foreign key on Category and return a full Category object.